# Do not select if additional character is included

Tags: regex

Suppose I have the following numbers:

> 3,000mt
>   300mt
>   44,000m
>   320m

And I want **44,000m** and **320m** to be selected.

What regex should I use to only select the numbers (comma separated) that have "m" in the end and not the ones that have "mt"?

This is what I have tried:

```
\d+[,]?\d+m.
```

I have no idea how to negate mt though.

Comment: This is what I have tryed. \d+[,]?\d+m. I have no idea how to negate mt though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close to the solution and only missed the possibility to check for a word boundary (represented by regex character `\b`). So instead of using any character `.` at the end of your regular expression, you will probably only look if the string is ended by a word boundary (e.g. spaces or newlines or nothing more):

```
\d+(,\d+)?m\b
```

where

- `\d+` looks for any digits (at least one)
- `(,\d+)?` looks for a comma followed by one digit or more (it's grouped by using parentheses and the whole group is completely optional using the `?` sign)
- `m\b` as explained above looks for a literal `m` at the end of a word

With this regex you can also match strings with one digit only followed by *m* like `9m` or similar. This is a slight change in comparison to your regex (grouping comma followed by digits).

I proved the regex via Python and also added some more edge cases:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "3,000mt 300mt 44,000m 1m 1mt 1,3mt 320m"
>>> re.findall(r"\d+(?:,\d+)?m\b", text)  # ?: is python specific for findall method
['44,000m', '1m', '320m']
```

Answer (score 1):

how about a unix solution like below

```
> echo "3,000mt 300mt 44,000m 320m" | tr ' ' '\n' | awk -F" " ' $0~/m$/ { print } '
44,000m
320m
>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have to do it with regex